# Can i bind classes to buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I'm learning kivy for a project and when i'm bind a class to a button instead of a function program runs but when i click the program terminates. Is it possible to bind classes or should i only bind functions?

Comment: You need to post a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: It has to be something executable.  It can be a function, a class member function, or a lambda.

Comment: Classes can have a `__call__` method, which automatically gets called if you call the class. So yes, you can bind classes, but you have to create a `__call__` method.

Comment: @TimRoberts A class is executable -- calling it constructs an instance of the class.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.